# AWS CloudFormation Outputs: Exporting AZ's

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Creating a layered stack set in cloudformation. Network Stack and App Stack

Just need the syntax to Output and Export two Availability Zones that are captured when a cfn user chooses them in the network template parameters dialogue.

eg, a user chooses two AZ's in a region via the usual mechanism.

```
AZoneNames:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>'
    Description: Availability Zones (choose two zones)
```

That captures the az's, and i assume, cfn indexes them [0,1] to an array in the background. That part works.

So I need to output the two az's and export them for the app stack but not sure how. I've attempted with the below snippet but it doesnt work

```
StackAvailabilityZone1:
    Description: The first az that was chosen at network stack creation
    Value: !Ref AvailabilityZone 0
    Export:
      Name: !Sub 'AZ1'
```

I'm sure its probably staring me in the face. Thanks so much for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following, using [Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html):

```
StackAvailabilityZone1:
    Description: The first az that was chosen at network stack creation
    Value: !Select [0, !Ref AZoneNames]
    Export:
      Name: AZ1
```